# See webserver response

Tags: debugging, web

When debugging a website (e.g. developed using Wicket), what client-tool one can use to see the webserver's exact response (e.g. 301 or 302)?

Comment: Why not add an answer?

Comment: [curl -v http://www.example.com](http://curl.haxx.se)

Comment: because it is too short and I don't like to make stuff up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use apt-get or similar to install wget and then do

```
wget -S http://localhost:8090
```

Where "localhost:8090" is the url path to the site
To see all headers from the GET request.  wget also has options that support POST requests

Alternatively use a browser with firebug to see the response codes

Comment: @MikeL. wget is available for most platforms, as is firebug